# ReactJS Flux: detect store data change between components (not parent and child relationship)

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have two components; menu and info. I need to share the data between the two components. I'm using Facebook Flux pattern. The store class has a change detection by EventEmitter. The detection works between parent and children relationship.

[image]

The blue is menu. The red is info component. My website didn't use ReactJS before. I am trying to use ReactJS into part of the site. I guess that using ReactJS for whole app is one possible solution, react-route..?,  but I cannot do that in this time.

Does anyone know about that?

================================

Edit 1

I posted my whole code to this gist.

https://gist.github.com/y-zono/e1abf9e85a4707d81286b49f6a7f0117

My goal is menu and info counters show same value. Now only menu counter is increased.

[image]

================================================

Edit2 Solved

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Menu = require('./components/Menu.react');
var Info = require('./components/Info.react');
var CommonStore = require('./stores/CommonStore');

function renderMenu() {
    var state = CommonStore.getState();
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Menu data={state} />,
        document.getElementById('menu')
    );
}

CommonStore.addChangeListener(renderMenu);
renderMenu();

function renderInfo() {
    var state = CommonStore.getState();
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Info data={state} />,
        document.getElementById('info')
    );
}

CommonStore.addChangeListener(renderInfo);
renderInfo();
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo here `CommonActionCreators.setMenuClieckOn()`. What exactly do not work ? Can you share your CommonActionCreators ?

Comment: Hi. I posted it. I'm sorry that is just type on stackoverflow. I modified some code for simple code.

Comment: I'm still not sure about Flux. I'm doubt that the store instance is not singleton. Only the dispatcher is singleton..?

Comment: Do you have any JSX in your components? What do you want to happen when the user clicks on the button

Comment: OK. I will edit my question. I'll put my whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subscribing to the stores at your component level, why not subscribe where you render the components (e.g. menu.js)?

You could wrap your rendering code in a function, and in that function read the store's state before passing it as a prop to your component. You would call `render()` manually to do your first render, but also subscribe to the store passing the render function as a callback:

```
// menu.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Menu = require('./components/Menu.react');
var CommonStore = require('../stores/CommonStore');

function render() {
  var state = CommonStore.getState();
  ReactDOM.render(
      <Menu data={state} />,
      document.getElementById('menu')
  );
}

CommonStore.addChangeListener(render);
render();
```

Note: I'm not sure what getters your store has, so i've just written some example code.

Your component code would then simply be:

```
// ./components/Menu.react.js
var React = require('react');
var CommonActionCreators = require('../actions/CommonActionCreators');

var Menu = React.createClass({
    _handleClickMenu: function() {
        CommonActionCreators.setMenuClieckOn();
    }
});
```

And then repeat the process for the `Info` component.

This fiddle shows an example of this approach working in practice (with some dummy components, store and action creators), to prove that the concept works: https://jsfiddle.net/vgskht45/1/

Comment: Thank you. I tried many times but still it does not work. I posted my all code to gist here. I'd like you can look at the code. https://gist.github.com/y-zono/e1abf9e85a4707d81286b49f6a7f0117

Comment: It works. Thank you! I posted the reason in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is you're not using your store to set the state in your components.

Info.react.js should be:

```
var React = require('react');
var CommonStore = require('../stores/CommonStore');
var CommonActionCreators = require('../actions/CommonActionCreators');

var Info = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        CommonStore.addChangeListener(this._handleChangeStore);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        CommonStore.remChangeListener(this._handleChangeStore);
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            clickFlag: CommonStore.getClickFlag()
        };
    },
    _handleChangeStore: function() {
        this.setState(clickFlag: CommonStore.getClickFlag();
        if (this.state.clickFlag) {
            console.log("menu is clicked"); // I want to detect the change.
        }
    },
});
```

Additionally, you will want to have a condition that resets your clickFlag.

UPDATE:

Looking at your code, you shouldn't have each component using their own separate `<script>`. Instead you should have a central js (frequently called app.js) which then displays both the menu and info components. You then don't need to separate menu into js/menu.js and js/components/Menu.react.js. Likewise, you shouldn't have the info component separated into js/info.js and js/components/Menu.react.js. You should just have js/components/Menu.react.js and js/components/Info.react.js, with app.js handling what you currently have js/menu.js and js/info.js doing.

Example:

index.html

```
<div>
  <div id="app"></div>
</div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Menu = require('./components/Menu.react');
var Info = require('./components/Info.react');

function renderDOM() {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
}

renderDOM();
```

Info.react.js

```
var Info = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        CommonStore.addChangeListener(this._handleChangeStore);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        CommonStore.remChangeListener(this._handleChangeStore);
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            count: CommonStore.getState()
        };
    },
    _handleChangeStore: function() {
        this.setState(count: CommonStore.getState();
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                info: {this.state.count}
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted my code to dist. I would be grateful you could see this code. https://gist.github.com/y-zono/e1abf9e85a4707d81286b49f6a7f0117

Comment: I had a great misunderstanding. Thank you so much.